# How to find Previous Sunday in R

Tags: r, date

It seems the Internet has not answered this question for R yet:

If I have a date. Say the 20th of march: as.Date("2015-03-20")
how do I get, in R, the previous Sunday?
i.e., in the above example, as.Date("2015-03-15").

Comment: No, please don't jump to this conclusion!

Comment: ok, i won't ;) 
----------------

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
d <-  as.Date("2015-03-18")
prev.days <- seq(d-6,d,by='day')
prev.days[weekdays(prev.days)=='Sunday']
# [1] "2015-03-15"
```

Answer (score 29):

Reading through the lubridate documentation, I found an answer.

```
library(lubridate)
date <- as.Date("2015-03-20")
previous_sunday <- floor_date(date, "week")
```

To get the previous monday, tues, etc. just add the required number of days:
(for monday)

```
day(date)<-day(date)+1
```

and substract 7 days if it is greater than the original date.

Comment: instead of adding an integer to the original date, you could also use floor_date's argument `week_start`

Answer (score 8):

```
cut(date_var, breaks='week', start.on.monday = F)
```

This works for me. It is available in base r and is bound to be faster.
**breaks** can be used to find start of ***day, week, month, quarter, year.***

Read
    ?cut &
    ?cut.Date

```
Sys.Date()
```

> [1] "2017-12-23"

```
cut(Sys.Date(), breaks = 'week', start.on.monday = F)
```

> [1] 2017-12-17
>   Levels: 2017-12-17

```
cut(Sys.Date(), breaks = 'month')
```

> [1] 2017-12-01
>   Levels: 2017-12-01

```
cut(Sys.Date(), breaks = 'quarter')
```

> [1] 2017-10-01
>   Levels: 2017-10-01

```
cut(Sys.Date(), breaks = 'year')
```

> [1] 2017-01-01
>   Levels: 2017-01-01

Comment: This seems to me like the canonical way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

One way:

```
d<-as.Date("2015-03-20")
d-as.POSIXlt(d)$wday
## [1] "2015-03-15"
```

There;s also the more hackish way, using the fact that dates are represented as integers with day zero being a Thursday (Jan 1 1970):

```
d-((as.numeric(d)+4)%% 7)
## [1] "2015-03-15"
```