# r: create custom "week" function

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I'm writing a function that will take my `df$date` field (which is daily `POSIXct` date (by day) and create a new variable called `df$wbm` (wbm = week beginning Monday). I know the math works because I've done this in Excel but the syntax is not working, see below:

```
df$wbm<- if (weekdays(df$date) == "Sunday") {
  df$date - days(6)
} else { df$date + (days(2) - df$date)
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get week starting date from a date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521371/how-to-get-week-starting-date-from-a-date-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked through several of the links, I found the last answer here to be the most helpful: [How to find Previous Sunday in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171025/how-to-find-previous-sunday-in-r)

This is what I came up with, using `lubridate`:

```
> df$wbm<- lubridate::floor_date(df$date, "week") + days(1)
> weekdays(df$wbm)[1]
[1] "Monday"
```

Answer (score 0):

`%w` might be the `format` argument you're looking for: it's day of week where Sunday is 0

```
> x <- as.POSIXct('2018-11-20 12:12:12')
> format(x, "%w")
[1] "2"
```